# Getting Exports from container in MEF (Lambda expression)

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3, lambda, mef

I am trying to see if the controller class name is the name of the controller name passed in. I think my lambda expression is wrong and that is why it isn't working properly. I am passing in the correct controller names, but the export variable is always null.

```
  Public Function CreateController(requestContext As System.Web.Routing.RequestContext,    
       controllerName As String) 
       As System.Web.Mvc.IController Implements 
       System.Web.Mvc.IControllerFactory.CreateController





    Dim controller As IController = Nothing

    If controllerName IsNot Nothing Then



        Dim controllerClassName As String = controllerName & "Controller"

        Dim export As Lazy(Of IController) = Me.container.GetExports(Of IController)().Where(
        Function(c)
            Return c.Value.GetType.Name = controllerClassName
        End Function
        ).FirstOrDefault()
```

If you need me to clarify anything, please let me know! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes your lambda expression is wrong, this should do the trick

```
Dim export As Lazy(Of IController) = Me.container.GetExports(Of IController)() _
                                              .Where(Function(c) c.Value.GetType.Name = controllerClassName) _
                                              .FirstOrDefault()
```